# React. Обновить стейт дочернего компонента по событию другого дочернего компонента, не вызывая render у родительского

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook

Есть компонент с формой фильтрации для данных таблицы, состоящий из компонентов полей формы. Есть компонент с таблицей.

Структура компонентов выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если значение в одном из полей фильтра изменилось, необходимо обновить состояние компонента `MyProjectsList` не меня состояние других полей фильтрации. Возможно ли это?

Comment: можно контекст использовать, либо еще одну обертку добавить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В таком случае есть 2 варианта. Создайте локальный стейт для каждого фильтра выше уровнем (в родительский компонент - ContentContainer) и распределите props (состояние) каждого фильтра по компонентам с фильтрами. Это позволит получить доступ к состоянию фильтров компоненте MyProjectList. Второй вариант, вынести стейт фильтров в глобальный, а не локальный. В таком случае MyProjectList - также будет иметь с этому стейту доступ